# Replace column names in dataframe based on a character vector that is ordered differently

Tags: r, sorting, data-wrangling

My question is how to rename my column names based on a character vector while imposing the order of the vector on my data frame. I have read all the similar posts, yet non responds to my question.

I am working on a data frame as such:

```
df<- data.frame(q3= c(1,4,6,1), q12=c(5,3,2,4), q11=c(1,2,3,4), q1=c(5,6,4,5),q5= c(1,4,6,1), q9=c(5,3,2,4), q10=c(1,2,3,4), q4=c(5,6,4,5),q2= c(1,4,6,1), q7=c(5,3,2,4), q6=c(1,2,3,4), q8=c(5,6,4,5))
```

Ideally I would like to order these columns base on their index i.e q1, q3, q78, q99. However this seems difficult.

To my luck, I also have a vector that contains the column names ordered:

```
cols<- c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4","q5", "q6", "q7", "q8","q9", "q10", "q11", "q12")
```

Replacing the data frame column names with `cols` is clearly incorrect since they are ordered differently. So where I have reached so far is:

`colnames(df) <- match(colnames(df), cols)`

`df <- df[,order(names(df))]`

which replaces the `colnames(df)` with the position in which the latter are found in cols but clearly I can't order these numbers since they are not perceived as integers by R (due to R not allowing numbers to be the names of variables). If I could do so, then df would be in the same order as cols and I would just replace the column names.

How can I make this work? If not possible, what could be an alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help? `df[,cols]`

Comment: Even If you don't have the `cols`, there are numerous ways to do it. A useful package for such task is `gtools`. Try `df[gtools::mixedorder(names(df))]`

Comment: @Sotos thanks a lot for the info, I'll definitely look into that in the future!

Comment: @NelsonGon it is funny how easy it was to fix, your suggestion worked as df –> df[,cols]!! If you could post it as an answer I will approve it as solved so that others can easily see the answer to the problem. Thanks again both of you.

P.s When you have a minute to spare I would really be interested to understand how the df[,cols] works internally. Since it's a type of subsetting how does it draw from an external vector and sort the df?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cols` to reorder the columns in our data frame:

```
df[,cols]
```

This basically uses the order of `cols` to reorder our data frame. This can be seen as follows:

```
df[,c("B","A")]
df[,c("A","B")]
```

If we had a vector named `cols` and set it as either `c("A","B")` or `c("B","A")`, we could then use this "trick" to help us reorder the columns.